# Could not start Browser / Emulator error on Nightwatch with Browserstack and Ms Edge 17

Tags: microsoft-edge, nightwatch.js, browserstack

I am using Nightwatch with BrowserStack to run a test suite on Ms Edge 17 and I am getting the following error in most builds.

```
Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server
Connection refused! Is selenium server started?
{
  value: { message: 'Could not start Browser / Emulator' },
  sessionId: '',
  status: 13
}
```

We have exactly the same code running on chrome browser in BrowserStack without any problems.
This suite runs in parallel using workers.  If I disable workers, then it passes, unfortunately we need to use parallel execution otherwise the suite would take too long.

I will post our config file below.

```
var seleniumJar = require('selenium-server-standalone-jar')
var nightwatchWorkers = parseInt(process.env.NIGHTWATCH_WORKER_THREADS) || 1 
var chromeDriver = process.env.CHROME_DRIVER_PATH || './drivers/chromedriver'
var msEdgeDriverPath = process.env.MSEDGE_DRIVER_PATH || './drivers/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe'
var ie11DriverPath = process.env.MSIE11_DRIVER_PATH || './drivers/IEDriverServer.exe'
var localDockerPort = 4444
var browserStackPort = 80
var browserStackHost = 'hub-cloud.browserstack.com'
var browserStackScreenResolution = '1920x1200'

module.exports = {
  src_folders: ['./tests'],
  output_folder: './results',
  live_output: true, //set to false so each thread will output the whole result of the test when it's done
  silent: true,
  custom_commands_path: './commands',
  custom_assertions_path: './assertions',
  page_objects_path: './pages',
  test_workers: {
    enabled: true,
    workers: nightwatchWorkers
  },

  selenium: {
    start_process: false,
    server_path: seleniumJar.path,
    log_path: './results',
    port: localDockerPort,
    cli_args: {
      'webdriver.chrome.driver': chromeDriver,
      'webdriver.edge.driver': msEdgeDriverPath,
      'webdriver.ie.driver': ie11DriverPath
    }
  },

  test_settings: {
    default: {
      launch_url: 'http://localhost',
      selenium_host: '127.0.0.1',
      selenium_port: localDockerPort,
      silent: true,
      disable_colors: false,
      screenshots: {
        enabled: true,
        on_failure: true,
        path: './results/screenshots'
      },
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        resolution: browserStackScreenResolution,
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true,
        elementScrollBehavior: 1,
        project: 'megarepo',
        build: process.env.BROWSERSTACK_BUILD_ID,
        'browserstack.user': process.env.BROWSERSTACK_USER,
        'browserstack.key': process.env.BROWSERSTACK_KEY
      },
      globals: require('./data/dev')
    },

    browserstack_msedge: {
      selenium: {
        port: browserStackPort
      },
      selenium_host: browserStackHost,
      selenium_port: browserStackPort,
      detailed_output: false,
      desiredCapabilities: {
        os: 'Windows',
        os_version: '10',
        browserName: 'Edge',
        browser_version: '17.0',
        resolution: browserStackScreenResolution
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We have exactly the same code running on chrome browser in BrowserStack without any problems.
This suite runs in parallel using workers.  If I disable workers, then it passes, unfortunately we need to use parallel execution otherwise the suite would take too long.

Comment: I check and find that there is some issue with service worker in Edge 17 in October, 2018 Windows update. I suggest you to install the latest Windows update to update the version of MS Edge and try to make a test with latest edge may help to solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. The problem is, this is an issue with BrowserStack.  It's not my own setup but a third party paid service. I will get in touch with them and see if they can update their windows os.

Comment: You can let us know your testing result after updating the latest updates. We will try to provide possible suggestions, if issue persist.